# Inserting a string into another string

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, nsstring

I am working on iPhone app. I have the SQL query:

```
 NSString *myRed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.4f", slideR.value];

 [self insertData:@"INSERT INTO colour VALUES("+myRed+")"];
```

It produces syntax error. How to insert a string into string. That approach in Java would have worked.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSString *myRed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.4f", slideR.value];

[self insertData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO colour VALUES(\"%@\")",myRed]];
```

If you don't want `"` then :-

```
[self insertData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO colour VALUES(%@)",myRed]];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing your query and your string appended together before hand.

```
             NSString *str = @"Your values";
             NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO color VALUES(%@)", str];
             [self insertData:query];
```